# jquery events do not recognise js-added html components?

Tags: jquery

I'm using js to add form elements into the html document. For instance, I'm adding an entire `<form>` to a table cell. Eg:

```
<form class="add-comment"><input type="submit" /></form>
```

I try to use js to invoke events based on elements within that newly created form but nothing happens. I should get an alert box. What am I doing wrongly?

```
$('.add-comment').submit(function() {
  alert('form submitted!');
});
```

Thanks.
Hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times on SO before, please try to look for similar questions before asking your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you adding the element after you register the submit event handler?  You will need to register the event after each new element, unless you use the live method to add the event.

```
$('.add-comment').live('submit', function() {
    alert('form submitted!');
});
```

This adds the event for all selected elements, even if they are added in the future.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Make sure to use the latest jQuery 1.4 for this technique, as any other version does not support the SUBMIT event.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! I tried adding both the element before and after the code that is the submit event handler but neither works. Using the .live() event worked though! :)

What did you mean to register the event after each new element? Thanks!

Comment: @Dave: Hmm..I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 and it seems to work. Am I missing something? Thanks :)

Comment: @Lyon, the element has to be on the page before you can wire it up to an event handler. `.live()` binds both current and future elements.

Comment: Take the following for example:

You add an element, then add the event.  The event works fine for the element.  

You add another element, but the event doesn't work.  You need to add the event to this element to get it to work as well.  This is what I meant by adding the event after every new element.  live() takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Newly-created elements do not have any event handlers attached to them. You'd have to select them and add the event handler after you've added them (eg. `$('.add-comment', newparent).submit(submitfunction)`).

You can generally use `.live(eventname, function)` to add event handlers for existing *and* future created elements. However you can't use `.live('submit', ...)` in jQuery 1.3 due to how these events are implemented in browsers (technically, they don't ‘bubble’).

jQuery 1.4 does support `live` against `submit` (through a really ugly hack).

Comment: Hi bobince, I'm using .live('submit', function () {}); and that's working in Chrome. From what you mentioned, this won't work in some browsers? How do I add the event handler after I've added them? I'm sorry but I couldn't understand your code. Thanks :) (I'm using jQuery 1.3.2)

Comment: Yes, it's IE's `onsubmit` that doesn't bubble (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536972%28VS.85%29.aspx); many other events don't work with `live` on IE or other browsers so you can't use it for everything. To select an element inside another element, you pass the parent element as  a context node into the `$(selector, context)` function.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [rather long blog post](http://jarrettmeyer.com/2010/01/18/editable-table-with-jquery/) regarding this if you're not using jQuery 1.4. You have to wire up the newly added elements, since they were not there when the page loaded. It should give you an insight into what is happening with the `.live()` method.

Comment: Thank you Jarrett. I followed your blog post and noticed you wire up the newly added elements by calling a function. I moved my original submit method into the function and called it everything I added a new form element and it worked! :) I guess this would work fully in jQuery 1.3.2. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Of course adding the event to the element is common worst practice. Try to find out about publish/subscribe style event handling, which can take the place of using the live plugin.

Comment: Thanks Bill. With your recommendations, I found LiveQuery. I'm using it to fire events for submit, blur and a function that doesn't work with event delegation (i think), while I'm using .live() for click and keyup. I also found an article that suggests .live() may be better for performance if the event works using .live(). The article is: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/432a0d9caae734db

Thanks again! I've learnt a lot through this episode and it's no thanks to all of you geniuses :)

Answer (score 0):

Kyle is right, you should use the live event to add events to current and future DOM elements. However, as an alternative, you can add the event when you create the form element:

(jQuery 1.4 style)

```
$('<form>', {
    id: 'myFormID',
    name: 'myFormName'
}).submit(function(){ alert('form submitted'); })
.appendTo(myDiv);
```